# Android : Apk not running after "Build Apk" Option

Tags: android, fragment, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I am not able to run the Apk from the Build Apk option rather than , when i deploy apk to phone via USB Debugging , the app runs very smooth and fine , no error in app causing it to force close . The problem is with the HomeActivity,this activity is only not loading while testing the App which contains fragments the code of the activity is given below.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh.R;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
                    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Use Gmail To Contact Us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendEmail();
            }

            private void sendEmail() {
                Log.i("Send email", "");
                String[] TO = {""};
                String[] CC = {""};
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"priyansh.mishra19@gmail.com"});
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Aaroh:Enquiry");
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " ");

                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send mail..."));
                    finish();
                    Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }


        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_homepage);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_homepage:
                fragment = new HomePage();
                break;
          case R.id.nav_coordinator:
                fragment = new Coordinators();
                break;
          case R.id.nav_events:
                fragment = new events();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                fragment = new About();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_developer:
                fragment = new Developer_info();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_contact:
                fragment = new Contact();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_winner:
                fragment = new Winners();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_timing:
                fragment = new Event_time();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_userprofile:
                fragment = new User_Profile();
                break;




        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

The code of the fragment Home_Page which is also not loading is given below

```
public class HomePage extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    ViewPager mPager;
    int images[] = {R.drawable.aump1, R.drawable.aump2 ,R.drawable.aump3, R.drawable.aump4};
    MyCustomPagerAdapter myCustomPagerAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    //@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homepage, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public  void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Home Page");


        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        mPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(HomePage.this.getActivity(), images);
        mPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
            int item_count=0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(item_count);
                if (item_count == 10) {
                    item_count=0;
                } else {
                    item_count++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            }
        } , 3000);

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Main_Home(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new Activities(), "Cultural Events");
        adapter.addFragment(new Competitions(), "Competition");
        adapter.addFragment(new Sponsors(), "Sponsors");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
        {

            super(manager);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Android Monitor Message :

```
10-06 23:21:20.888 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
10-06 23:21:23.649 14028-14028/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-06 23:21:25.706 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Session started, time: 540154589
10-06 23:21:25.711 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
10-06 23:21:25.712 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh D/FA: Logging event (FE): _s, Bundle[{_o=auto}]
10-06 23:21:25.713 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Using measurement service
10-06 23:21:25.713 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Connecting to remote service
10-06 23:21:25.721 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh D/FA: Connected to remote service
10-06 23:21:25.721 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
10-06 23:21:25.730 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=session_start(_s),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto}]
10-06 23:21:25.738 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: session_start(_s), 14
10-06 23:21:25.739 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh', name='session_start(_s)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto}]}
10-06 23:21:25.745 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 216
10-06 23:21:25.777 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
10-06 23:21:25.780 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
10-06 23:21:25.780 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
10-06 23:21:25.822 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 93
10-06 23:21:25.997 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Sending upload intent from DelayedRunnable
10-06 23:21:26.004 29459-29459/? V/FA-SVC: Device receiver got: com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
10-06 23:21:26.017 29459-29459/? V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService is starting up
10-06 23:21:26.017 29459-29459/? V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService called. startId, action: 1, com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
10-06 23:21:26.019 29459-14142/? D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10057
10-06 23:21:26.022 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Fetching remote configuration: com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh
10-06 23:21:26.023 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, false, false
10-06 23:21:26.218 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: onConfigFetched. Response size: 0
10-06 23:21:26.222 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Successfully fetched config. Got network response. code, size: 304, 0
10-06 23:21:26.265 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Saving bundle, size: 404
10-06 23:21:26.266 29459-14142/? D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10272
10-06 23:21:26.269 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh, 494, 
                                           batch {
                                             bundle {
                                               protocol_version: 1
                                               platform: android
                                               gmp_version: 9452
                                               uploading_gmp_version: 11517
                                               config_version: 1506927976668530
                                               gmp_app_id: 1:18560328138:android:a0727ccc4b032b68
                                               app_id: com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh
                                               app_version: 1.0
                                               app_version_major: 1
                                               firebase_instance_id: eppKbsaWKHU
                                               dev_cert_hash: -1076636081997616382
                                               app_store: com.google.android.packageinstaller
                                               upload_timestamp_millis: 1507312286233
                                               start_timestamp_millis: 1507312275893
                                               end_timestamp_millis: 1507312285707
                                               app_instance_id: 061ef57a7bc88835a2cb2c3761e50960
                                               resettable_device_id: 8bf60814-8360-4cd7-8abc-fee8d9e1ae5f
                                               limited_ad_tracking: false
                                               os_version: 7.0
                                               device_model: SM-G935F
                                               user_default_language: en-us
                                               time_zone_offset_minutes: 330
                                               bundle_sequential_index: 1
                                               service_upload: true
                                               user_property {
                                                 set_timestamp_millis: 1507312275893
                                                 name: first_open_time(_fot)
                                                 int_value: 1507312800000
                                               }
                                               user_property {
                                                 set_timestamp_millis: 1507312275893
                                                 name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
                                                 int_value: 1
                                               }
                                               event {
                                                 name: first_open(_f)
                                                 timestamp_millis: 1507312275893
                                                 previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                 param {
                                                   name: firebase_conversion(_c)
                                                   int_value: 1
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                   string_value: auto
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: _r
                                                   int_value: 1
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: previous_first_open_count(_pfo)
                                                   int_value: 12
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: system_app(_sys)
                                                   int_value: 0
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: update_with_analytics(_uwa)
                                                   int_value: 0
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: system_app_update(_sysu)
                                                   int_value: 0
                                                 }
                                               }
                                               event {
                                                 name: user_engagement(_e)
                                                 timestamp_millis: 1507312275893
                                                 previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                 param {
                                                   name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                   string_value: auto
                                                 }
                                                 param {
                                                   name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
                                                   int_value: 1
                                                 }
                                               }
                                               event {
                                                 name: session_start(_s)
                                                 timestamp_millis: 1507312285707
                                                 previous_timestamp_millis: 0
                                                 param {
                                                   name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
                                                   string_value: auto
                                                 }
                                               }
                                             }
                                           }
10-06 23:21:26.269 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, true, false
10-06 23:21:26.275 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
10-06 23:21:26.276 29459-14976/? V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. size: 425
10-06 23:21:26.452 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599997
10-06 23:21:26.457 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
10-06 23:21:26.457 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
10-06 23:21:26.464 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
10-06 23:21:26.474 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
10-06 23:21:26.481 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
10-06 23:21:26.481 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Stopping uploading service(s)
10-06 23:21:26.482 29459-14142/? V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService processed last upload request. StartId: 1
10-06 23:21:26.482 29459-29459/? V/FA-SVC: Device PackageMeasurementService is shutting down
10-06 23:21:29.925 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Activity paused, time: 540158808
10-06 23:21:29.959 14028-14028/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: onActivityCreated
10-06 23:21:30.072 14028-14063/com.darkweb.android.amityaaroh V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 540158955
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your question

Comment: The app is not working , when i try building apk and installing is via APK